# Proper way using async/await making parallel calls

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I am struggling with how to do this properly in nodejs. This tries to do two things in parallel:

- downloads a webpage using axios
- creates a directory

When those are finished:

- save result asynchronously to a file in de created directory

Then waits until done

```js
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const axios = require('axios')
const path = require('path')

const mkdir = util.promisify(fs.mkdir)
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)

const downloadPage = async (url='http://nodeprogram.com') => {
 console.log('downloading ', url)

 const fetchPage = async function() {
  const folderName = uuidv1()
  return axios
   .all([
    mkdir(folderName), 
    axios.get(url)
   ])
   .then(axios.spread(function (f, r) {
    writeFile(path.join(__dirname, folderName, 'file.html'), r.data);
   })); 
 }

 await fetchPage()
}

downloadPage(process.argv[2])
```

Comment: So, what is exact question?

Comment: How to do it properly :-) I think there might be a mistake in the placement of asyncs/awaits and return and declaration.

Comment: Not near computer to type exact example, but what I see now: 1. Remove async in fetchPage declaration. 2. Put write file call after await fetchPage line, so remove 'then...' with it in fetchPage definition

Answer (score 0):

Your question and sample are looking contradictory. Question says, you need to make use of async and await to make parallel calls, but your sample code shows you need sequential calls instead of parallel.

Best use of Async/Awaits are for making sequential calls.

**async** function is a kind of shorthand function for 'Promise', were things are done implicitly like returning will be considered as 'resolve'.

**await** should always be within **async** function, add **await** on functions you need to wait for before proceeding further.

Syntax change in **await** function is, instead of

```
somePromiseFunctionCall().then( (someVarible) => {...}).catch(e => {})
```

you need to use

```
const asyncFunction = async (parameters) => {
    try {
        // First Function call that returns Promise / async 
        someVariable = await somePromiseFunctionCall();
        // Second (sequential) call that returns Promise / async
        someNewVariable = await someotherPromiseFunctionCall();
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

Now, in your sample, if your requirement is to wait for axios to return and then create folder and then write the result to file, that can be done using async and await.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 writeFile(path.join(__dirname, folderName, 'file.html'), r.data);
```

to this:

```
return writeFile(path.join(__dirname, folderName, 'file.html'), r.data);
```

You need to return the promise from writeFile so it is added to the chain so that the promise you're returning from `fetchPage()` is linked to the `writeFile()` operation.  As your code was originally, the `writeFile()` operation is proceeding on it's own and is not connected at all to the promise you were returning from `fetchPage()` so when you do:

```
await fetchPage()
```

it wasn't awaiting the `writeFile()` operation.

---

A cleaned up version could look like this:

```
const downloadPage = (url='http://nodeprogram.com') => {
    console.log('downloading ', url)

    // don't really need this separate fetchPage() function    
    const fetchPage = function() {
        const folderName = uuidv1()
        return axios
            .all([
                mkdir(folderName), 
                axios.get(url)
            ])
            .then(axios.spread(function (f, r) {
                return writeFile(path.join(__dirname, folderName, 'file.html'), r.data);
            })); 
    }

    return fetchPage()
}
```

Then, you would use it like this:

```
downloadPage().then(() => {
   // page is downloaded now
});
```

Or, inside an `async` function, you could do:

```
await downloadPage();
// page is downloaded here
```

Note, that I removed several cases of `async` and `await` as they weren't needed.  `await fetchPage()` wasn't doing you any good at the end of `downloadPage()`.  From a timing point of view, that does the exact same thing as `return fetchPage()` and this way, you're actually resolving with the resolved value of `fetchPage()` which can be more useful.  There did not appear to be any reason to use async or await in `downloadPage()`.  Keep in mind that an `async` function still returns a promise and the caller of that function still has to use `.then()` or `await` on the return value from that function.  So, using `await` inside of `downloadPage()` doesn't change that for the caller.